# Continuous signal to multiple pulses

Tags: signal, control-system, pulse

I need help creating a simple circuit. Essentially what I would like to accomplish is that by pushing a button to close a circuit, I would like to take that continuous signal and create multiple pulses, say 1 second apart. The pulses are only to keep going as long as the button is pressed and are stopped when the button is released.

Basically when I close the circuit by pushing a button, I want to turn it into multiple on-off pulses spaced 1 second apart for as long as the button is pushed. Keep in mind I have next to no knowledge of electronics, so if you could guide me in layman terms, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: search for 555 timer. http://www.electroschematics.com/4843/1-hz-pulse-generator/

Comment: Thanks @Umar. You can put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. That link led me to search for this, which I think is exactly what I need, and I don't even have to build the circuit. http://www.ebay.com/itm/NE555-Duty-Cycle-Adjustable-Pulse-Frequency-Square-Wave-Signal-Generator-Module-/192001544024?hash=item2cb42f0f58:g:Xj4AAOSw8w1YB1v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for 555 timer. http://www.electroschematics.com/4843/1-hz-pulse-generator/

Below excerpt from 
http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/operating-modes.html
An Astable Circuit has no stable state - hence the name "astable". **The output continually switches state between high and low without without any intervention from the user**, called a 'square' wave. This type of circuit could be used to give a mechanism intermittent motion by switching a motor on and off at regular intervals. It can also be used to flash lamps and LEDs, and is useful as a 'clock' pulse for other digital ICs and circuits.

The switch can be implemented just as a power pin to the IC, so that whole set up is in OFF state when the switch is released. When the switch is pressed train if pulsed will be generated, duration of pulse width of which is defined by the external time constant (R and C).